# 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have three images that I am trying to display in `UIPageView` but every time I swipe to the third image, I get this error: `'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'`

I have checked other question regarding this same issue but can't figure out where my issue resides.

Here is the rest of the output:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a410c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010a0a9bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a30717e -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 190
    3   BonBUp                              0x0000000109b1a1cb _TFC6BonBUp14ViewController21viewControllerAtIndexfS0_FSiCS_21ContentViewController + 619
    4   BonBUp                              0x0000000109b1a792 _TFC6BonBUp14ViewController18pageViewControllerfS0_FTCSo20UIPageViewController33viewControllerAfterViewControllerCSo16UIViewController_GSqS2__ + 418
    5   BonBUp                              0x0000000109b1a84f _TToFC6BonBUp14ViewController18pageViewControllerfS0_FTCSo20UIPageViewController33viewControllerAfterViewControllerCSo16UIViewController_GSqS2__ + 79
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010afc2c67 -[UIPageViewController _queuingScrollView:viewBefore:view:] + 129
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010b06044c -[_UIQueuingScrollView _viewAtIndex:loadingIfNecessary:updatingContents:animated:] + 247
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010b0625c2 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _adjustContentInsets] + 316
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010b060135 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _replaceViews:updatingContents:adjustContentInsets:animated:] + 763
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010b063287 -[_UIQueuingScrollView _didScrollWithAnimation:force:] + 1082
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010b05f42b -[_UIQueuingScrollView layoutSubviews] + 155
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010aacb9eb -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f122ed2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f1176e6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f117556 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f08386e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f084a22 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
    18  QuartzCore                          0x000000010f146085 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 489
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a378174 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a377d35 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a339d3d __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a339366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ec4ba3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010aa4b8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    25  BonBUp                              0x0000000109b21327 main + 135
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010cfe2145 start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here is the code within my **ViewController**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {


    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController!
    var pageImages: NSArray!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.pageImages = NSArray(objects: "jeans.png", "blusas.png", "leggings.png")

        self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

        var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController
        var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(viewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 60)

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController
    {

        var vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController

        vc.imageFile = self.pageImages[index] as! String
        vc.pageIndex = index

        return vc


    }


    // MARK: - Page View Controller Data Source

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {

        var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int


        if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil

        }

        index--

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        var vc = viewController as! ContentViewController
        var index = vc.pageIndex as Int

        if (index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil
        }

        index++

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
    {
        return 0
    }


}
```

And **ContentViewController**:

```
import UIKit

class ContentViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var pageIndex: Int!
    var imageFile: String!



    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: self.imageFile)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint at ` func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController` and see from where is it called with index = 3 ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is what I get when I put a breakpoint there: http://imgur.com/ZY5lEoa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not checking if `index >= self.pageImages.count` to return `nil` in `viewControllerAtIndex` method, so when you are on last page it will ask fro `viewController` after and you will end up crashing due to index out of bound, your method should look like this.

```
 func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> ContentViewController?
    {
        if index >= self.pageImages.count
        {
            return nil
        }
        var vc: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController

        vc.imageFile = self.pageImages[index] as! String
        vc.pageIndex = index

        return vc

    }
```

As your method can return nil now, so I added `?` at the end of method, and you need to make some changes in code as well to use this now.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification but I am getting the following error when I implement that `if` statement: `Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'NSArray!'`. I also noted you added a `?` to `ContentViewController` hence I had to modify the code in `viewDidLoad` `var startVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0) as ContentViewController?` and add the `?` there too. Also an `!` in `var viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC!)` under the same method since they were showing me errors.

Comment: i Updated the if statement, it was count

Comment: I added ? because this method can return nil if index is out of bounds.. you need to make some changes

Comment: Got it working. Thanks! One more question, is there any way to make each image clickable and take them to different Navigation Controllers?

Comment: yes you can add UITapGestureRecognizer to UIImageView

Comment: So it would be adding somethings like this under `viewDidLoad` method under each image? `var tapGestureZoom = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "jns:")
        tapGestureZoom.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGestureZoom.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        pageImages.userInteractionEnabled = true
        pageImages.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureZoom)`

Comment: Add tap gesture inside viewDidLoad of ContentViewController where you are adding `imageView`... 
`var tapGestureZoom = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "jns:") 
self.imageView.add(tapGestureZoom)`

Comment: I am getting this error: `'UIImageView' does not have a member named 'add'` should I change it to `imageView`? Also, do I have to add this code once or for each image?

Comment: its addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureZoom)

Comment: Ok, do I have to add an `IBAction` like this: `@IBAction func Jns(sender: AnyObject?){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Jeans") as! Jeans
    }` And then connect `ContentViewController to `NavigationController` by adding a custom segue?

Comment: you need to implement method which you provide as action ... func ins(){
// create view controller here which you want to push, or 
// if you have an segue in storyboard  then call performSegue method
}